# Why Doesn't the Code Deadlock

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, locking, task-parallel-library

Can some please explain to me why this code doesn't cause a Deadlock?

```
static Object listlock = new Object();

void StartAsync()
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            lock(listlock)
                base.OnPropertyChanged("MyList");
        });
}

 public ObservableCollection<MyObjects> MyList
 {
    get
    {
         lock(listlock)
             return  new ObservableCollection<MyObjects>(_myObjectList);
    }
 }
```

Some background details:
The program is using **MVVM** Pattern and **MyList** is bound to a **Datagrid** on the **WPF UI**.
**_myObjects** is just a random list of Objects.
Is it because the **OnPropertyChange** just informs the UI that it has to go get the New Data from MyList and just returns without caring whether the UI actually gets the Data or Not?
 I know that the OnPropertyChanged is called on a separate Thread but the UI exists on a single thread (doesn't it O.o) so the thread that gets informed is also the thread that gets the Data. I would of thought that lock wouldn't have been able to release because of that?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but i think that the property changed event just adds a dispatcher job for the wpf binding engine to retrieve it at a later point, propably in another dispatcher job. So yes your lock is released because when the event is raised, its not yet calling the getter. You could check that in the debugger if you are still in the same callstack. Again i'm not sure that its actually the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key realization here is that the handler of `PropertyChanged` does schedule some code that accesses `MyList` on the UI thread, but it **does not wait for it to finish**.

So, one possible sequence of events is this:

1. `StartAsync()` takes the lock on a background thread.
2. `PropertyChanged` for `MyList` is raised.
3. The handler for `PropertyChanged` schedules code that accesses `MyList` on the UI thread.
4. The handler for `PropertyChanged` returns.
5. The lock is released.
6. UI thread attempts to access `MyList`.
7. UI thread takes the lock without waiting, because no other thread owns it.
8. …

Another way to put it: What I think you expected is that the handler for `PropertyChanged` does something like:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "MyList")
    {
        var newList = model.MyList;
        // set newList as the current value of some binding
    }
});
```

But in fact, it does something like (the only difference is the first line):

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "MyList")
    {
        var newList = model.MyList;
        // set newList as the current value of some binding
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok so I was semi correct in my assumption then? The OnPropertyChanged simply goes tells the UI to go get the new Data and then returns, hence as you stated the BeginInvoke :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For deadlock to happen on single lock you need 2 threads in such a way that first thread **grabs the lock and wait** for second thread to grab the same lock. You will not get deadlock otherwise (i.e. there is no wait for other thread *inside* `lock` statement, or there is only one thread involved).

Note to future readers - below is not what happens in WPF case  - see svick's answer. Just generic example of no deadlock with 2 locks on the same thread:

One possible case is when listener for OnPropertyChanged calls `MyList` in response to the synchronous notification on the same thread (check out call stack when `MyList` is called). In this case nested `lock` does nothing since thread requesting the lock already holds it.

Comment: @svick, your answer seem to be much close to reality. Keeping this one for historical reasons.